# Send message to MQTT server using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, android, web-services, mqtt

I want to implement push notification for an android app compatible for 2.1. I have gone through the [article](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/) by Anton Lopyrev. Really Small Message Broker by IBM is ok for me. But the server side of the app is developed in ASP.net. So I have to replaced the drop-in PHP library named `SAM`. Is there any way to implement to use `MQTT (Really Small Message Broker or Mosquitto)` using ASP.net?

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if you really need to use that at all...

Why not going with [**Amazon Simple Queue Service**](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) instead of trying to make all that work with pieces and bites from a lot of places?

> Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) and Amazon SNS are both messaging services within AWS, which **provide different benefits** for developers. Amazon SNS **allows applications to send time-critical messages to multiple subscribers** through a **“push” mechanism**, eliminating the need to periodically check or “poll” for updates.

As (you don't say, I'm just assuming) **Really Small Message Broker** can not be hosted in a Shared Hosted and you will probably have seveal issues on set everything up correctly.

Comment: We have dedicated server for that. So it is not a problem for us.

Comment: so... with a Windows Server, and so many PHP sample code out there, why not host it in the windows server, and then you can consume if you want, using ASP.NET. Just to let you know that you don't need ASP.NET specific code if you have a windows server, you can easily install and run any other language, perl, php, etc ...